# Find between two string dictionary where string not equals; linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have two dictionary

`dicA` fill from DB , `dicB` fill from Excel columns.

`dicA.Values` maybe equals `dicB.Values` but most of the time `dicB.Values` contains `dicA.Values`

**Problem:**
I want to find all of Values in `dicB` that has contain `dicA.Values` and add to new dictionary `dicNew` , `dicNew.Key=dicA.key` and `dicNew.Values=dicB.Values`

**My solution**
I wrote this code:

```
 Dictionary<string,string> res = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var s in dicB)
        {
            var data = dicA.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(s.Value)).ToList();
                //check if data.count==1 add to autoBind
                //    autoBind.Add(data[0].Key,data[0].Value);
                // else find in data which value string has most equals
                // character then add this to Autobind 
        }
```

Is there other way (better than my code) to find All dictionary data can match and add them to `autobind`?

Edited: 
`dicA.key` doesn't  equal `dicB.key`. I want to find if `dicA.value` is in  `dicB.values` then if `dicB.values.count==1` add to `newDic` else find best match; which `dicB.Values` string have most same character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dictoinaryResult = dictionaryB.Where(x => dictionaryA.ContainsValue(x.Value)).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: This above code will return a dictionary object with mapped key values.

Answer (score 1):

use this code as Sample Format

```
Dictionary<int, string> abc = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            foreach (var a in dicA)
            {
                foreach (var b in dicB)
                {
                    if (a.key == b.key)
                    {
                        abc.add(Convert.ToInt32(a.key, b.value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `a.key` not equal `b.key`. if a.value string is in b.values then add to new dictionary

Comment: then u can change with 'if (a.Value== b.value)
                    {
                        abc.add(Convert.ToInt32(a.key, b.value);
                    }'

Comment: it is a sample code i provide fro this u can take the requirements according to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var dicNew = dicB.Where(b => !dicA.ContainsValue(b.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dictionary<int,string> dicta = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> dictb = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        dicta.Add(1, "Hi");
        dicta.Add(2, "Hello");
        dictb.Add(2, "Hiyo");
        dictb.Add(1, "Hllow");

        var list = (from d1 in dicta
                   let temp = dictb.FirstOrDefault(d2 => d2.Value.Contains(d1.Value))
                   where temp.Value != null
                   select new { d1.Key, temp.Value }).ToDictionary(d => d.Key ,d => d.Value );
```

i hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in elegant way by using your own IEqualityComparer

```
class ValueComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> x, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> y)
        {
            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> obj)
        {
            return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And then you can simply use

```
var dictC = dictA.Intersect(dictB, new ValueComparer<string, string>())
```